# Using R how do i remove all text letters after the first numeric value appears in the string?

Tags: r, string

For example i have a column called values

```
    values|
 Col has 32
 Has Col 43
 Mor 434524
 Hi 4343433
C 434343 is
```

I would like it to be

```
    values|
   Col has 
   Has Col
       Mor
        Hi
         C
```

Comment: Do you have a dataframe, llist, vector or string?? could you provide the `dput(your_data)`?.

Comment: this is just a list.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a list? Could you show how it looks in R?. paste the output of `dput(your_list)`  also try `gsub("\\d","", your_Data)` and see what you get

Comment: it's not the numbers i only want to delete. I want to delete everything starting from the first number

Comment: `gsub("\\d.*","", your_Data)` The problem is that we do not know how your data is set in R. you should consider posting the `dput` of your dataset

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. how would i do that?

Comment: So you had a vector and not a list. In that case, `sub("\\s*\\d.*","", your_Data)` is what you are looking for. This will ensure you remove the trailing spaces